# How can i gain weight with a strange body type?

Tags: weight-gain

Im a 25 years old male that has been skinny all his life (around 55-60kg). I have a body type that the times i have eaten too much, i get fat only the stomach. The arms, legs etc didnt change.
Now i would like to get bigger, around 70-75kg all the body, and i was reading the book that you guys recommended here "Starting Strength by Mark Rippetoe".
Due to this type of body, is something else i would have to do apart from what is writen in the book and all the excellent answers you are giving in the questions about gaining weight?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just get lifting. Where your bodyfat places itself says nothing about how you should train (and at a novice level the difference between how people should train isn't that big). Somewhat related: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13886/weight-training-advice-for-ectomorph-female/13909#13909 (the "Regarding Ectomorphs")

Comment: Do lots of cardio. Don't listen to BS answers here recommending programs that make you do squats and deadlifts. Your situation will become even worse b/c you'll get. a big posterior AND a big flab. Do cardio first and get rid of the flab.